# How to find options available when installing an application using Installshield

Tags: command-line, perforce, installshield

I am trying to install Perforce Helix using Chef. Install file is an .exe file with 4 options available to install. I want to install 3 of them excluding one. Is there a way to identify which option to provide to it from command line. Currently I am able to install package in silent mode and with default settings using

```
installer_type :custom
  options %W[
    /s 
    /v/qn
  ].join(' ')
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Look at Perforce Helix docs, searching for "silent install", or try running the executable with `--help` flag. If they do not provide option to install only some of the options, chef will not help you.

Comment: Going to remove the Chef tag because this question is not actually about Chef.

Comment: It's sort-of a question about Chef because there are other automation tools that can run a Windows installer and select certain options (e.g., using GUI automation of the dialogs and check boxes) during the install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, I got the solution. I first installed the application and then removed P4ADMIN from it:

```
`installer_type :custom 
options %W[
    /s 
    /v"ADDLOCAL=ALL REMOVE=P4ADMIN /qn" 
].join(' ')`
```